# Angular2 Unexpected closing tag "li"

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular 2, I am using node npm to run angular.Without looping its working quiet good.
I am getting 'Unexpected closing tag "li" ("' in browser while compiling.
[have tried this but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244639/angular-2-parsing-template-error)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'test',
        template: `<ul>
<li *ngFor="let carPart of carparts">
    <h2>{{carPart.name}}</h2>
        <h2>{{carPart.description}}</h2>
        <h2>{{carPart.inStock}} in Stock</h2>
            </li>
    </ul>`
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        carparts = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Super Tires",
            "description": "These tires are the very best",
            "inStock": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Reinforced Shocks",
            "description": "Shocks made from kryptonite",
            "inStock": 4
        }];
    }

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Try posting the real code or make a plunker. It makes it hard to help when there are so many differences from the real code. Others have noticed the casing of variables but i also see a missing reference to 'this' that i doubt you would get away with?

Comment: For more information about this error please go to this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642501/7487135)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
<h2>{{carPart.name}}<h2>
```

It should be:

```
<h2>{{carPart.name}}</h2>
```

Also you use wrong variable name

```
<li *ngFor="let carPart of carParts">
```

In your class is using `carparts`.

And because you're using angular beta version it should be

```
<li *ngFor="#carPart of carparts">
```

You can use `let` only since beta17. See also more information here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-beta17-2016-04-28

> Inside of structural directives that declare local variables, such as
>   *ngFor, usage of #... is deprecated. Use let instead.  now becomes

Comment: it works, <li *ngFor="#carPart of carparts">
 this resolved my problem, may i know why i cant use 'let' there\

Comment: `let` is for RC versions of angular 2. start using RC4 version.

Answer (score 3):

I think your error lies here :

```
<h2>{{carPart.name}}<h2>
```

You accidentally opened to `h2` - instead of closing it. You're missing a `/` in your end-tag.
You are actually inside two `h2` elements that you need to close before closing your `li`.

Comment: Even this didn't work `<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let carPart of carParts">
     <h2>{{carPart.name}}</h2>
   <h2>{{carPart.description}}</h2>
   <h2>{{carPart.inStock}} in Stock</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>`

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi The error you get is because the template can't be parsed. Try posting a plunker - that might detect the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an deprecated version of angular2, please update to RC4.
Since angular precompiles html, if you have any closing tags missed also will result in error