# Unexpected closing tag "div" error angular2 HTML

Tags: html, angular

I'm getting some errors in the console and not sure what is the issue is in the `HTML`. Any help would be appreciated.

> error_handler.js:51 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template
>   parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "div" ("             Click here to Signup       
>     [ERROR ->]  "): ResetPassword@22:1 Error: Template
>   parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "div" ("             Click here to Signup       
>     [ERROR ->]  "): ResetPassword@22:1

```
<section class="reset-password">
<div class="container container-responsive inner-top-xs">
    <form [formGroup]="resetPasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="resetPassword(resetPasswordForm.value, resetPasswordForm.valid)">
        <h4>Please enter your e-mail address and a temporary password will be sent to you.</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <validation-message [control]="resetPasswordForm.controls.email"></validation-message>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat__blue outer-top-xs" [disabled]="!resetPasswordForm.valid">RESET PASSWORD</button>
    </form>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger outer-top-xs" *ngIf="errorMessage && !successMessage"">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      {{errorMessage}}
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success outer-top-xs" *ngIf="successMessage">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      {{successMessage}}
    </div>
    <div class="outer-top-xs">
        <a [routerLink]="['/getstarted']">Click here to Signup</a>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got one double quote too many at `*ngIf="errorMessage && !successMessage""`:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger outer-top-xs" *ngIf="errorMessage && !successMessage"> 
<!--at the end of this line-->
```

Comment: There is hardly a better example of a case for using the "typo" close reason.

Comment: @torazaburo ohhh, is there such a thing? I did not know! :) then yes, you are definitely right

Comment: Oh my. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurred when you open an element and don't close its.
this error shows up in this example:

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'facilities'">
 <ion-item *ngFor="let facility of facilities">
  <ion-icon name="facility.Icon" item-start></ion-icon>
  {{facility.Name}}
  <ion-icon color="red" name="rose" item-end></ion-icon>
 </ion-item> 
<ion-list>
```

As you see I don't close `<ion-list>` element (should be `</ion-list>`)

**Be careful:**

If you use any element properties with its values as the parser can't handle them, the element will be opened and this error occurs( "" at above example).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error because my component name started with a number (ex: <10-component-name></10-component-name>).

Changing the name to only  fixed the issue.