# Angular 2 Unexpected closing tag

Tags: html, angular

Im having trouble with Angular 4 and html. I get unexpected closing tag  first. When I remove the form closing tag, then I get the same error but with .
Im a rookie by the way, so it may be a very dumb mistake. Here is the code, thanks!

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card mx-2">
          <div class="card-block p-2">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <p class="text-muted">Create your account</p>
            <form *ngIf="creatingUser"
              class="example-form"
              (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)"
              #userForm="ngForm"
              fxFlexFill [fxLayout]="'row'"
              fxLayoutAlign="center start">
            <div class="input-group mb-1">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
              <input type="text" fxFlex="100"
               required
               minlength="3"
               placeholder="Username"
               [(ngModel)]="user.profile.username"
               name="username"
               #username="ngModel">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-1">
              <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" #email="ngModel" id="email"
               required
               pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
               placeholder="Email"
               [(ngModel)]="user.profile.email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="select">Select role</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="select" name="select" size="1" placeholder="Role" [(ngModel)]="user.role" name="role">
                  <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{role.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-1">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" #password="ngModel"
               required
               minlength="6"
               [(ngModel)]="user.password">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" name="repeatPassword" #repeatPassword="ngModel"
               validateEqualTo="password"
               type="password"
               required
               placeholder="Confirm Password"
               [(ngModel)]="user.confirmPassword">
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Create Account</button>
            <button type="button"
              [color]="'warn'"
              (click)="creatingNewUser(false)">
            </button>
            <button type="submit"
                    [color]="'primary'"
                    [disabled]="!userForm.form.valid">
            </button>
            </form>
            <div *ngIf="!creatingUser">
              <button [color]="'primary'" (click)="creatingNewUser(true)">
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer p-2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-facebook" type="button"><span>facebook</span></button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-twitter" type="button"><span>twitter</span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the **exact** and **full** error message. Also formatting the code properly is mandatory if you want others to find such an error. If you need support with the formatting, please just add a comment to your question. A good strategy to find the error yourself would be to step-by-step remove markup until the error goes away.

Comment: For more information about this error please go to this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642501/7487135)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one extra `</div>` at bottom. You can check it here - [html linter](https://dirtymarkup.com/)